# Converting IF (w/ ISTEXT, FIND, MID to convert date to proper format) statement to custom VBA function

Tags: excel, vba

I received a workbook from a colleague who does not use a consistent date format. The IF statement below outlines my thought process in trying to create a single IF statement that can convert the string or number into the proper date format by using MID and FIND:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(F49),MID(F49, FIND("/",F49)+1, FIND("/",F49, FIND("/",F49)+1)-FIND("/",F49)-1)&"/"&LEFT(F49,FIND("/",F49,1)-1)&"/"&RIGHT(F49,2),TEXT(F49,"dd/mm/yy"))
```

I am bit of a novice when it comes to VBA and wanted to create a custom function that can implement the steps outlined in the IF statement above. Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

GG

Comment: What is the date format you received and what is the date format you require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are converting European to local American dates. There's several methods to do this:

a) VBA function [e.g. =ConvertDates(F49)]:

```
Function ConvertDates(ValueDate As Range)
Dim Dates() As String
Dates = Split(ValueDate.Text, "/")
ConvertDates = Dates(1) & "/" & Dates(0) & "/" & Dates(2)
End Function
```

b) Sheet formula (simplified version):

```
=IF(ISTEXT(F49),MID(F49,4,3)&REPLACE(F49,4,5,""),TEXT(F49,"dd/mm/yy"))
```

c) Select the dates in the column and choose:

Data > Text to Columns > Next > Next > Column Data Format: DMY

I think the third option might be quickest as you don't need to create a new column.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. The reason why my original IF statement was a bit complicated was because the sender of the original excel workbook isn't consistent in the way she presents the dates. Although in European date format, she is sometimes putting dates in as 12/12/01, 09/9/12, 9/04/04 etc. That is why I felt the need to use the FIND function to find the location of the /'s the numbers between them, etc.

Comment: Ok, I see why the formula is more convoluted, I've adjusted the VBA function to allow for different length date representations. Text to Columns should work in any case.

Comment: lori_m, thank you for your response and output. After reading and trying out your code suggestion, I went back and learned the VBA functions that you utilized above and was pleasantly surprised by the simplicity and intuitiveness, and how well it works. Thank you again for your help/advice.

Comment: Glad this worked for you. For others' benefit please indicate if it answers the question. Thanks